# Compare dateTime "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" with "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" in c# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

How to check dateTime greater than with below format date Time.

In "CreatedDate" column have below format values.

```
Created Date
    2020-03-01 10:59:50.250
    2020-03-01 10:40:39.610
    2020-03-01 10:39:18.087
    2020-02-29 07:39:18.087

 public IQueryable<UserProfile> GetTopUserProfiles(System.DateTime startDateTime)
 {
   return GetDbContext(toUpdate).Get<UserProfile>( w =>w.CreatedDate >= startDateTime);
 }


 var dtstart = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     statDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dtstart).AddHours(8); //add 8 hours to current date.
    //start DateTime value: 3/1/2020 8:00:00 AM

 var count = _userProfileRepository.Value.GetTopUserProfiles(startDate).Count();

count is returning 0. 
Expected count is 3
```

Comment: Quick test, do you get any results if you don't use the .AddHours(8) - time/date is funny - my guess is that the values are materialized in C# from the DB in UTC. Try it out. If it works without the .AddHours, that's probably why.

Comment: I have to always check with today's date 8:00 AM

Comment: I realize - it's just a test - to see if perhaps your DB values get materialized as UTC.

Comment: If you use `DateTime.Date`, you'll get a DateTime with no time component, i.e., at midnight. So, for example, `DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(8)` will result in 8:00 am this morning

Comment: I hard coded startdate to "03/01/2020 8:00:00" but still count returning to Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You no need to convert to `yyyy-MM-dd`.

You should consider whether the server time value between `.NET` back-end and `SQL` Database is the same or not.

Comment: The problem is data in SQL and conditional in `.NET` code. Is that the same server of different?

Comment: Same server, can we store "yyyy-MM-dd" format in DateTime? e.g. dt= somve value??

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
return GetDbContext(toUpdate).Get<UserProfile>( w => DateTime.Compare(w.CreatedDate,startDateTime) > 0);
```

Comment: I want to check with >=  , not a compare.